# Extract the value from the html input element before sending to the sql server

Tags: html, mysql, server, geolocation

For now, I have a form that the user inputs the lat and long, and I use those information to create markers and send them to the mysql. However, I want to change to have the user input the address instead, and I tried to use the geocode from google api to get the lat and long from the address the user give me. However, it failed miserably. I think the form is sent to the server before I can catch the address value.  So I am not sure how to get the address out of the form before it is sent to the server? Anything would help. thanks

This is my html file

```
<form id = "seenform" action="/submitseen" method="POST">

        <input placeholder="Latitude" name = "lat" id="lat">
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Longitude" name = "lngt">
        <br>
        <input id="address_seen" placeholder = "Address" name = "address"> (this is where I want to get the value out)
</form>


Javascript file

app.post('/submitseen', function(req,res){
    var dlat = req.body.lat;
    var dlngt = req.body.lngt;
    var daddress = req.body.address;
})
```

Comment: how do you submit the form? I can't see any button to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the form values before submit.

```
document.getElementById('seenform').onsubmit = function() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address_seen');
    console.log(address.value);
};
```